# Flask-SQLAlchemy __table__ AttributeError for Only One Model in Multi-Model Setup

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I need some assistance with a Flask and SQLAlchemy setup I have. I'm loading my models in the following manner:

```
from models import User
from models import Project, ProjectForm
from models import Prompt, PromptForm
from models import Transaction
from models import Notification
from models import imageGeneration
from models import Package
```

Here's what my models/__init__.py file looks like:

```
# models/__init__.py

from .User import User
from .imageGeneration import imageGeneration
from .Prompt import Prompt
from .PromptForm import PromptForm
from .Project import Project
from .ProjectForm import ProjectForm
from .Transaction import Transaction
from .Notification import Notification
from .Package import Package
```

During app initialization, when creating the database, I load all models like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.warning('SqlAlchemy: Creating tables')
    with app.app_context():
        User.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        Project.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        Prompt.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        Transaction.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        Notification.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        imageGeneration.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        Package.__table__.create(bind=db.engine, checkfirst=True)
        ### here I'm starting the app
```

However, I'm encountering an error specifically with the Package model:
`AttributeError: module 'models.Package' has no attribute '__table__'. Did you mean: '__file__'?`

The definition for my Package model is:

```
from app import db
import uuid


class Package(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'packages'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.String(36), default=lambda: str(uuid.uuid4()), 
                     unique=True, nullable=False)  
    name = db.Column(db.String(225), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.FLOAT(precision=10, decimal_return_scale=2))
```

Any ideas what might be wrong with my code?

All the other models load fine. I'm only experiencing issues with this particular model. I've tried renaming it and even printed the content of the file in case Docker wasn't copying it correctly. I'm just excepting the package table to be created.

Comment: I'd advice following [naming convention for packages and modules](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names): all-lowercase, with possible underscores. It would also make it impossible for a module to shadow a variable. As for the problem, don't you have `from . import *` somewhere?

Comment: No, I never use that as a best practice.

Comment: I don't see how any of this can be working, as `__table__` isn't created until the ORM class is mapped.  Are you sure that `db.create_all()` isn't being called somewhere?  (As a matter of interest, why not just use `db.create_all`?)

Comment: It's actually not working for me and not creating the tables at all.

Comment: I would remove all the `Model.__table__.create` stuff and replace with `db.create_all()` as documented [here](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/#create-the-tables).